# Лучший способ для хранения токена в Android приложении

Tags: java, android

Я создал приложение и думаю над тем, как наиболее безопасно хранить токен, который получаю при авторизации в своем сервисе. Как я понял, SharedPreferences для этого не очень подходит. Читал про AccountManager, но не понял насколько он безопасно хранит токены. Хотел бы увидеть пару примеров безопасного хранения с получением и сохранением.

Comment: Вот буквально на неделе статья была на хабре по вопросу: https://habr.com/post/423753/

Comment: Для хранения токенов и прочей чувствительной инфы используйте AccountManager. SharePreference не используйте, не просто так все разрабы гугла делали, чтобы мы почти в чистом виде все хранили в файликах.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Comment: https://moluch.ru/archive/273/62244/
Если коротко, то используй Account Manager

Answer (score 2):

Я совсем недавно начал заниматься созданием клиент-серверного приложения для android, и как вы понимаете с сервера мне в определенный момент использования приложения мне приходят два токена: refresh и access. Первый используется в запросах на доступ к информации, а второй используется для того чтобы обновить первый. Вся фишка access_token в том что у него есть время протухания, у меня например это время равно пол часа.

Теперь собственно ближе к самому вопросу - как хранить токены? У меня тоже возникал этот вопрос, и в итоге я пришел к выводу что их вполне можно хранить на устройстве при помощи SharedPreferences. Сначала я парился: а вдруг найдут, и будут использовать для доступа к моей очень важной информации, даже думал может его шифровать и на телефон кидать уже тогда. Но потом я прочитал пару статеек, и там было написано что токен это и так зашифрованный ключ а шифровать зашифрованное как-то тупо. Так же для доступа к токену нужны root-права. И все-равно даже если они (эти права) у вас, или у ваших пользователей  будут, то это нужно очень сильно запарится чтобы найти эти токены, и все-равно человеку нужно будет знать адрес сервера, параметры и вид запроса.

Короче я вам советую пока сохранять на телефоне, а если уже будут проблемы, то думать над этим вопросом. Надеюсь чем-то помог в вашей ситуации. Удачи, у вас все получится :)